# Wordpress can't not illustrate the WP Githuber MD's full function[Solved]

Tags: wordpress, markdown

I've used the WP Githuber MD to edit my article.And my edit page is like this.It can illustrate the code block and quote block.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA9Zb.png)
But when I change to my website, it didn't work,what is the problem . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtUjo.png)

what can I do to solve it.(I want to have the same Effect as the edit page does),it can make my website neater.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Share more details just here.

Comment: thanks a lot， I 've just solved the problem, when I change my wordpress theme that can support markdown structure.(theme:yocto)

Comment: sounds great. If you have any issue more, Feel free ask.